# Prove $(x+1)e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)x^k}{k!}$ using Taylor Series.

Tags: calculus

Prove $$(x+1)e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)x^k}{k!}$$ using Taylor Series.

I can see how the  $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$ plops out, but I don't understand how $(x+1)$ can become $(k+1)$.

Comment: Hint: Try to find a series expension for $xe^x$ and add that to the series of $e^x$.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} (xe^x) = (x+1)e^x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$xe^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}.$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$.

Comment: Yikes,I feel like an idiot for not thinking of that! Guess I'm just a purist at heart and like to compute things directly if possible.

Comment: The formula kind of yells derivative. If one does work with formal power series in combinatorics, shift/differentiation/integration to obtain new from old become very natural.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite: 
$$(x+1) e^x = xe^x + e^x $$ then use your series representation for $e^x$.

Comment: I was actually expanding out the Taylor series directly and then rearranging term by term, but that IS a clearer computation and harder to mess up,Stefan.........: )

Answer (score 1):

$(k+1)x^{k}/k!=x \frac {x^{k-1}}{k-1!} + \frac {x^k}{k!}$

Comment: why is this wrong?:P

Comment: It is not wrong. The sentence "It's very simple." may bother the OP, and I do not think it is a very polite way answering a question. The equality that you have put also seems more like a comment rather than an answer, as you do not explain what to do with it.